# Pass string from my function (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function

So i want to write a a function of the form

```
function [ output_args ] = job(n,sigma,tau,rho,p,N,'Gaussian')
```

because inside the function i want to pass the 'Gaussian' as an argument to a matlab build-in function like

```
pd = makedist('Gaussian')
```

So then i want to use the function for multiple uses changing 'Gaussian' to 't' and other strings. How can i implement this?

Could somebody help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just declare the variable in the argument list of your function and pass that variable to `makedist` in the function body. There's no black magic here.

Comment: What if i want to pass it in the title of a figure?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by TroyHaskin, you can define a string argument for your function and use it in your function body to call a matlab built-in function:

```
function [output_args] = plot_figure(X, dist_type, my_title)
    pd = makedist(dist_type);
    Y = pd.pdf(X);
    figure; plot(X,Y);
    title(my_title);
end
```

And then, you can try differents values:

```
plot_figure(-10:10, 'Normal', 'Distribution plot');
plot_figure(-10:10, 'Gamma', 'Another distribution plot');
```